# SPFx - PnP-JS-Core - Check if list exist in current web

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp-js-core

I want to check if list(by Display Name) exist in current web.

In [pnp developer guide](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Developer-Guide) is no information on how to work with lists?

I need this for validate web property and i want to use pnp-core-library to do this:

```
private asyncTextBoxValidationMethod(value: string): Promise<string> {
if (value !== undefined && value.length > 3) {
  var url = this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + `/_api/web/lists?$filter=Hidden eq false`;

  return this.fetchLists(url).then((response) => {
      var lists: ISPList[] = response.value;
      var foundList: boolean = false;
      lists.forEach((list: ISPList) => {
          if (value === list.Title) {
              foundList = true;
          }
      });

      if (!foundList) {
        // resolve promise with error message to display..
        return Promise.resolve("Value entered did not match a list in this site!");
      }

      // otherwise resolve promise with an empty string..
      return Promise.resolve("");
    });
  }
```

}

How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `lists.ensure` method to check if the list exists or not.

Add the below import statement:

```
import pnp, { List, ListEnsureResult } from "sp-pnp-js";
```

In your method, you can use it as below:

```
// Use lists.ensure to always have the list available
pnp.sp.web.lists.ensure("Custom List").then((ler: ListEnsureResult) => {
    if (ler.created) {
        console.log("list was created");
    }
    else{
        console.log("list already existed");
    }

    // work on the created/updated list
    const r = await ler.list.select("Id")();

    // log the Id
    console.log(r.Id);
}
```

Reference - [PnP Core debugging](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Debugging)

[Using PnP with SPFx](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/guidance/use-sp-pnp-js-with-spfx-web-parts)

Comment: If list does not exist, then ensure function creates it. Which is sometime not ideal. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, it creates a new list. Which is not always ideal, but it has been modelled on the `web.ensureUser` method which checks if user exists , if not adds it to user info list and then gives you the user object. Having said that, you can use `lists.ensure` to also check if a doc lib exists or not like `pnp.sp.web.lists.ensure("DocLib","",101).then(...` etc. It can be use for lists of any templates as well :)  Let me know if need more details :)

Comment: Many thanks for this information. You are doing a very good contribution on SP.SE, keep it up. :)

Answer (score 3):

I have tested the PnP List existence check against SP Online. You may try the same with SPFx without SP.SOD

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sp-pnp-js/2.0.7/pnp.js">
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){
$pnp.sp.web.lists.filter("Title eq Employee34'").get().then(function(result) 
{
   if (result.length > 0) {
      alert("List Exists");
   } else {
      alert("List Does Not Exist");
   }
});
});
});

</script>
```

**On Testing :**

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a good approach.